# Reading RSA Private Key in PEM format And Reading public Key from certificate

Tags: c#, rsa, digital-signature, x509certificate

I'm trying to use a PEM(X.509) certificate (stored in a privateKey.pem file on disk) to sign messages.After that i need to verify signature by using certificate (sent to the receiver).
Help with this, especially example code in c# and RSA algorithm

Comment: I'm afraid that an answer to your question would have to include a primer on public key cryptography, something I'm not willing to do nor do I think is appropriate for stackoverflow. I will offer just a few tips.

Answer (score 1):

You may find the [Bouncycastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/) C# library to be of value in your problem. There is a PEMReader class that should be able to read in your PEM file and convert the contents to Bouncycastle cryptography objects. And there is a DotNetUtilities class to provide a bridge between Bouncycastle and .NET cryptography objects.

Answer (score -1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms819963.aspx

This is how you can sign message using x509 certificate.